# Ошибка при добавлении приложения в Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

Всем привет.
Не могу добавить приложение, из-за ошибки:
"Добавьте в приложение поддержку временной блокировки аккаунта до 1 ноября 2020 года"
У меня простенькое приложение без подписки, я совершенно не понимаю что от меня хотят :с
Буду рад любой помощи, заранее спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Надо заполнить эти формы.

[image: Надо заполнить эти формы.]

[![Доступ к приложению, Реклама, Возрастные ограничения, Целевая аудитория.

Обратите внимания, там кнопки "Далее" или Сохранить внизу справа.][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlCnz.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlCnz.png)

Comment: Прикол в том - что эти предупреждения горят и на старых играх. Где эти формы были заполнены. И что делать не совсем понятно.